# Listen on orientation changes

Tags: java, android

Trying to listen to orientation change in my android program, but nothing works.
My solutions:
Added `android:configChanges="orientation"` to my activity in AndroidManifest
and added this in my Activity class:

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        Log.d(TAG_ZT, "Config changed.");
        navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_translator);

    }
```

But it doesn't work.

Next my solution was adding:

```
OrientationEventListener orientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext()) {
        @Override
        public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
            Log.d(TAG_ZT, "onOrientationChanged: "+orientation);
            navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_translator);
        }
    };
```

But also No work.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: when developing for API level 13 or higher (as declared by the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion attributes), you must include the "screenSize" value in addition to the "orientation" value. That is, you must decalare `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`

Comment: @shadygoneinsane you was a little bit late.
But also Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be using API level 13 or higher. In this case use `configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`
otherwise onConfigurationChanged will not be called.

Comment: Great!
Thank you, will use it in future to.
Now everything works OK.